# How to view PDF in new tab when link is clicked?

Tags: php, laravel

when i click the link, it downloads the pdf file and not viewing it

Controller-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
public function show($id)
{
    //
    $currentissue = CurrentIssue::find($id);

    $tableof = DB::table('tableof_contents')
        ->select('*')
        ->where('title_journal', '=', $currentissue->title)
        ->get();

    return view('currentissue.viewcurrentissue', ['currentissue' => $currentissue, 'tableof' => $tableof]);
}
```

View-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
@foreach ($tableof as $tableof1)

<a href="{{ URL::to($tableof1->content) }}" target="_blank">{{$tableof1->content_title}}</a>
<ul><li><span class="lnr lnr-user"></span> {{$tableof1->author}}</li></ul>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

add target="_blank" in anchor tag.

```
<a href="path of your pdf file" target="_blank>Download/View PDF</a>.

@foreach($target as $res)

<a href="{{URL::to('/'.$res->path)}}" target="_blank" title="" class="">Download/View PDF</a>

@endforeach.
```

Comment: i have added that already but it downloads the pdf file when i clicked the link. it should view the link in new tab and not download it

Comment: On which browser you are trying?

Comment: what is your $res->path returning? Try to give a full Name of file with extension for demo.